# Keplerian to cartesian elements issue

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements, python

I am trying to convert between keplerian orbital elements to cartesian position and velocity but something is going wrong. The issue is that I (as a check) compute some keplerian orbital elements with these derived cartiesian position and velocity but the values do not match (I give an example below where the eccentricities do not match which is referred to as check1 in the code). I am trying to code the equation given in,[Keplerian_to_cartesian](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M001-Keplerian_Orbit_Elements_to_Cartesian_State_Vectors.pdf)

```
def kep_2_cart(a,e,i,omega_AP,omega_LAN, EA):

nu = 2*np.arctan(np.sqrt((1+e)/(1-e)) * np.tan(EA/2))
#4
r = a*(1 - e*np.cos(EA))
#5
h =  np.sqrt(mu*a * (1 - e**2))
#6
Om = omega_LAN
w =  omega_AP

X = r*(np.cos(Om)*np.cos(w+nu) - np.sin(Om)*np.sin(w+nu)*np.cos(i))
Y = r*(np.sin(Om)*np.cos(w+nu) + np.cos(Om)*np.sin(w+nu)*np.cos(i))
Z = r*(np.sin(i)*np.sin(w+nu))

#7
p = a*(1-e**2)

V_X = (X*h*e/(r*p))*np.sin(nu) - (h/r)*(np.cos(Om)*np.sin(w+nu) + \
np.sin(Om)*np.cos(w+nu)*np.cos(i))
V_Y = (Y*h*e/(r*p))*np.sin(nu) - (h/r)*(np.sin(Om)*np.sin(w+nu) - \
np.cos(Om)*np.cos(w+nu)*np.cos(i))
V_Z = (Z*h*e/(r*p))*np.sin(nu) - (h/r)*(np.cos(w+nu)*np.sin(i))

r_vec = np.array([X,Y,Z])
v_vec = np.array([V_X,V_Y,V_Z])

ang_mom_vec = np.cross(r_vec,v_vec)

e_vec = (np.cross(v_vec,ang_mom_vec) - (mu * r_vec/(np.linalg.norm(r_vec))))/mu


#As a check make sure the magitdue of e_vec = e and ang_mom_vec = h
check1 = np.linalg.norm(e_vec) - e
check2 = np.linalg.norm(ang_mom_vec) - h

return [X,Y,Z],[V_X,V_Y,V_Z]
```

Comment: @uhoh I have edited the question where I have added a link to the equation I am trying to program.

Comment: @uhoh  sorry about that,I have added a pdf with the equations

Comment: @uhoh no problem, I really have tried to write out the steps in Python and everything seems ok (in my head), but when I try to get the orbital elements back from the cartesian vectors (outputted) the magnitudes don't match with what I put in...so I am really confused

Comment: @uhoh not sure if this helpful, but there supposedly a matlab code that does this, https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35455-convert-keplerian-orbital-elements-to-a-state-vector?s_tid=mwa_osa_a

Comment: Quick sanity check: All your angular measurements -  (orbital inclination i, Argument of Periapsis omega_AP,  Longitude of the ascending node omega_LAN, and Eccentric Anomaly EA  ) are being passed in as radian values, correct?

Comment: @notovny yes that is correct

Comment: Why are you not using the suggested _arctan2_ function (`np.arctan2` in Python+numpy) to ensure that the result is in the correct quadrant, regardless of inputs ?  assume this is Python3+ and you are not getting integer division by default?

Comment: @astrosnapper I also tried using arctan2 but I still have the same problem. The magnitude of the eccentricity derived via the cartesian elements does not equate to the input eccentricity.

Comment: @Warrenmovic `from poliastro.core.elements import coe2rv` https://docs.poliastro.space/en/latest/api/core/elements.html#poliastro.core.elements.coe2rv and also you might need `from poliastro.core.angles import E_to_nu` https://docs.poliastro.space/en/latest/api/core/angles.html#poliastro.core.angles.E_to_nu

Comment: @astrojuanlu I tried that and it seems to work! thanks!. I am not sure why my own code failed but I am very glad this code works.